Javascript multiple fetch calls in sequence
I'm trying to make multiple fetch calls in sequence. So the first call works just fine, however, when I try to make the second call after the first call, it throws the 500 error. I've Been trying to mess with the client side as well as the server side all day but just have no clue. So what I'm doing below is making two fetch calls in sequence, with just a different method and a different url.
First call (POST) that works
async func1(){
try {
  // debugger;
  await fetch('http://apiDomain/Ready', {
  method: 'POST',
  }).then((rsp) => {
  if(rsp.ok) {
    console.log(rsp.json());
    this.func2();
    }
   });
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    alert("Error: ", error);
  }

So when the func1 returns rsp.ok, then I call another call (GET), func2.
async func2(){
try {
  // debugger;
  await fetch('http://apiDomain/ReadySetGo', {
  method: 'GET',
  }).then((rsp) => {
  if (rsp.ok) {
     console.log(rsp.json());
     }
    });
   }
   catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
     alert("Error: ", error);
  }

(apiDomain is an .asp.net app that is running under IIS in a dev server)
I also called func2 independently after func1 (then()) not as nested, also tried Promise.all to call both but no matter what I do, as soon as the first call returns, the second one (not only just ReadySetGo but any urls) will just throw the 500 (Internal Server Error - An Error has been occurred in IIS logs).
Not really sure why the first one returns 200 just fine but the second one always fails.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What do the logs say? Why mix await with then()?

so any GET results in a 500 error ... perhaps your "apiDomain" doesn't have any GET endpoints? though, that SHOULD result in a Method Not Allowed error ... the issue is with the server, it's not likely anything you've shown will cause an internal server error

do the independent calls work fine?

You could use chaining
fetch('http://apiDomain/Ready', { method: 'POST' })
  .then(response => {
    // Check if the response is ok (status in the range 200-299)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }

    return response.json();  // Parse JSON data from the response
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Use data from the first request
    const something = data.something;

    return fetch('http://apiDomain/ReadySetGo', { method: 'GET' });
  })
  .then(response => {
    // Check the second response is ok (status in the range 200-299)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }

    return response.json();  // Parse JSON data from the second response
  })
  .then(details => {
    console.log({ details });  // Handle the data from the second request
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle any errors that occurred during any of the fetch operations
    console.error('Failed to fetch data:', error);
  });

